# Does offline data persist in Firebase RTDB after app closes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hybrid-mobile-app

**Scenario**: An app uses Firebase DB to save data. A user commits an update to Firebase DB while it is offline, then closes the app.

- Will the data exist/persist after the app restart? `window.localStorage` gets cleared when a phone is low on memory, therefore becomes unreliable to save persistent data.
- What does the Firebase DB SDK use to save offline data? WebSQL? IndexedDB? File? SQLite?
- Will it be reliable to save persistent data while the app is offline? Firebase did mention it's offline capability in the documentation, but says that it was meant for *temporary offline*. To what extent does the term *temporary* mean? Does it mean while the app is still open? Or per session? Or depending on memory space?
- What do you recommend to use for offline database for hybrid app? PouchDB? LokiJS? IndexedDB?

Comment: Depends on wich technology you are developing (Android / IOS / Unity / Web). (for Unity see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133222/2798897 )

Comment: @Nik I highly suggest you look into Firebase Cloud Firestore instead of RTDB